# dynamic shoping cart price rule based on text atribute value contain sku of another product apply 10% discount

Tags: magento, cart, rule

I have two attribute sets of product default is for wine and other one if for its case. I have add one text attribute in case attribute type product to add sku of wine from default attribute set. I want to apply 10% discount on purchase of same case of wine.

So, i want to set dynamic shoping cart price rule based on text atribute value contain sku of another product apply 10% discount

Thanks, 
Rajesh Puraswani

Comment: There really isn't a question here. It would also be helpful if you included what you've already tried. Also, as one last suggestion, you might try cleaning up your title to be more concise.

Comment: let me know the logic for the 10% discount so i can create rule for you...

Comment: in shoping cart rule where we enter sku at that place i want dynamic value which is attribute value of other product in cart same time..